# Remove operation in JsonPatch builds an incorrect path with duplicate indexes for arrays

Tags: json-patch

Basically the same issue as in - https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch/issues/121

Is there a way to overcome this
or
Is there any alternate to JsonPatch library which gives the diff of 2 jsons similar to JsonPatch but with correct paths

Build diff using JsonDiff.asJson() with the following jsons:

Current

```
{
  "id": "Contract 1",
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "First document"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Second document"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Third document"
    }
  ]
}
```

Modified

```
{
  "id": "Contract 1",
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "First document"
    }
  ]
}
```

Removed last two objects from array

Expected Behavior
Json Patch document

```
[
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/documents/2"
    },
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/documents/1"
    }
]
```

Actual Behavior
Json Patch document

```
[
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/documents/1"
    },
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "path": "/documents/1"
    }
]
```